# How to get websphere application server installation directory using shell script

Tags: shell, websphere

I have a WebSphere Application server (WAS) installed in the path `/opt/IBM/WebSphere`.

Is it possible to get the installation path using OS user `wsadmin`?

I need to get that installed directory path from shell script.

Answer (score 1):

If you're in a profile directory (or always know where one is,) you could check variables.xml, which exists at /config/cells/(your_cell_name_here)/nodes/(node_name_here)/variables.xml for the value of WAS_INSTALL_ROOT. For example (not necessarily the cleanest):

```
INSTALLROOT=$(grep "symbolicName=\"WAS_INSTALL_ROOT\"" variables.xml | grep -o "value=\"[^\"]*" | cut -b8-)
```

There is also an installation registry, which is /opt/.ibm/.nif/.nifregistry for WAS before 8.0 and /opt/.ibm/.was.installlocations.registry for 8.0 and above, however these are created and edited by the installation wizard so they may not be 100% accurate to what's installed on the system. This [developerWorks answer](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/answers/295913/view.html) explains a little more about those files.